# Overwite/remove app bundle that is already in "Ready to send for review" in play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

We recently added a new release to production track and turned on Managed Publishing. The app was in "Ready to send to review". We sent it for review and and app got approved also. Then it was in "Ready to Publish" section. We found out we need to upload a new app bundle as the approved one had some issue. So, we removed the changes from "Ready to publish" but now it's in "Ready to send for review" section again and we can't remove the app from there.

We need add new app bundle in the production track and send that one for review. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply upload a new app bundle with a higher version code, and send it for review. The new bundle will override the old one, and you will only have the option to release the new one after it passes the review.